# A more elegant way of creating tuples of tuples from lists

Tags: python, django, forms, tuples

I'm using Python 2.7 and want to create a choice in a Django form.  I have a dictionary of the items I want in the choice drop-down but want to know the most pythonic way to handle this.

Here is my solution:

```
my_dict = {
    'AL' : 'Alabama',
    'AK' : 'Alaska',
    etc...
}

my_list = []
for value in (my_dict):
    my_list.append('({0}, {1})'.format(value, gateways.get(value)))

my_tuple = '({0})'.format(','.join(my_list))

print my_tuple


(('AL', 'Alabama'),('AK', 'Alaska'),etc...)
```

This will work, but it didn't look very elegant to me.  Can someone suggest a better solution?

Comment: You are creating strings, not tuples.. And your output will be `((AL, Alabama), (AK, Alaska), ...)` as coded (no quotes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you do not necessarily need a tuple for create a choice, quite a list:

```
>>> d = {'AL' : 'Alabama', 'AK' : 'Alaska',}
>>> d.items()
[('AK', 'Alaska'), ('AL', 'Alabama')]
```

For tuple:

```
>>> tuple(d.items())
(('AK', 'Alaska'), ('AL', 'Alabama'))
```

Comment: I can dig it...Thanks.  This is much more elegant.

Comment: Sorry defuz, I missunderstood the conversation, apologizes for all.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a list comprehension to replace the loop

```
my_list = ['({0}, {1})'.format(value, gateways.get(value)) for value in my_dict]
```

And even write it directly as a generator expression in the generation of `my_tuple`

```
my_tuple = '({0})'.format(','.join('({0}, {1})'.format(value, gateways.get(value)) for value in my_dict))
```